# Can we use "Continue with Email" instead of signup/login?

Tags: usability, mobile, login, web, social

I was working on a product and while making the signup/login buttons I thought of providing the **Continue with email/social** instead of login and signup buttons separately.

Will it affect the cognitive load? 
And based on the recall and recognition fact, will it be usable? as the people are more active to signup - sign in/login words instead of **connect** where there will be the same step for making an account or using it again.

[image]

**Connect with email logic** will work like, we'll provide just two fields, email ID/username and password. Once the user inputs the details, there will be searching in the DB and if the entries match the DB row, then the user is regular user, he/she can go inside and use the portal otherwise, new row will be created and the time he/she enters, there will be welcome message saying welcome to the portal.

I just have a general idea about the database and the data creation. Also, before proceeding with this idea I want to be sure that it'll come into play for the users with an ease.

Comment: The first thing which comes to my mind is "Where it will take me?" "Am I already Logged in? " If I don't have an account, how will system understand, that you are new to the system (If you are merging Login and SignUp).

If we talk about "recall and recognition" this will increase the user learning curve. There is a chance of user's Slips, what if he doesn't want to login? Users mental model will search for sign up button.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it is a little convoluted. The word ***continue*** creates cognitive overload in this situation. First of all, I have to start guessing what is the difference between logging and continuing if I haven't already signed up.

I would recommend to use ***continue*** before a major change is about to take place for the user. 
Eg: *You are about to modify your x & y details. Do you want to continue?*

My recommendation is to keep the logging and signing up separate and offer in both places the option to do it via e-mail or facebook.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Continue is not a reference for people used to Web apps and is not clear action for people not used to it imo.

I would use "login/sign up with email".

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree. Glassdoor.com has this on their homepage for non-signed in users, but other sites make it clear. I will say they make it slightly clear that you are creating a new account. Being explicit is way better.

Comment: Please use a comment instead of an answer when commenting on other answers (I know that you may not have the necessary reputation to do so).